# How can I config the name of my pages in a dash app?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a dash webapp with multiple pages defined as *.py-files in the subfolder **pages**. Currently the names in the dropdown are based on the *.py-file in the **pages**-folder. How can I change the name of the page without adapting the filename?

Below is a minimal example of a dash app with the page **overview**. I would like to show this in the **DropdownMenu** as **1 - overview** instead of **overview**.

**app.py:**

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash_bootstrap_templates import load_figure_template


app = dash.Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX]
                )
                
load_figure_template("LUX")


navbar = dbc.NavbarSimple(
    children=[
        dbc.DropdownMenu(
            [
                dbc.DropdownMenuItem(page["name"], href=page["path"])
                for page in dash.page_registry.values()
                if page["module"] != "pages.not_found_404"
            ],
            nav=True,
            label="More Pages",
        ),
    ],
    brand="- - - - Financial Evaluation",
    brand_href="/",
    id = "id-navbar"
)

dash.register_page("home", layout="We're home!", path="/")



app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        navbar,
        dash.page_container,
    ],
    className="dbc",
    fluid=True,
)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server

(debug=True)
```

**pages/overview.py:**

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html

dash.register_page(__name__)

SIDEBAR_STYLE = {
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": 0,
    "left": 0,
    "bottom": 0,
    "width": "16rem",
    # "padding": "2rem 1rem",
    "background-color": "#f8f9fa",
}

sidebar = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2("Filter"),
    ],
    style=SIDEBAR_STYLE,
)

content = html.Div(id="page-content")
layout = dbc.Row(
    [
        dbc.Col(sidebar, width=2),
        dbc.Col(content, width=9),
    ],
    className="g-0",
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When registering pages with `dash.register_page` you could pass a value to the `name` parameter.

> name: The name of the link. If not supplied, will be inferred from module, e.g. pages.weekly_analytics to Weekly analytics

https://dash.plotly.com/urls#reference-for-dash.register_page

---

As an aside: If you only want to add the `[number] -` prefix to each dropdown item, you could also do that without changing the page `name`. For example:

```
[
  dbc.DropdownMenuItem(f'{index+1} - {page["name"]}', href=page["path"])
  for index, page in enumerate(dash.page_registry.values())
  if page["module"] != "pages.not_found_404"
]
```